# How to map <C-z> to act like <C-y> in completion menu?

Tags: key-bindings, popup-menu, ins-completion

My keyboard has z and y switched compared to US keyboards, which makes pressing `C-y` for completions pretty awkward. I tried adding

```
imap <expr> <C-z> pumvisible() ? "<C-y>" :"<C-z>"
```

based on some examples I found but it doesn't seem to work in the popupmenu. How can I map `C-z` to accept completions?

Comment: That's working for me. You could have a plugin interfering with the mapping. What happens if you use `vim -u NONE` (or `nvim -u NONE --noplugin`)? You could also try `inoremap` to prevent any potential recursive mappings.

Comment: Damn, yes, exactly that is the problem. I forgot that `coc.nvim` switched to their own completion menu and I was using that ...

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, my issue was with a plugin (`coc.nvim`). To have both `coc.nvim` and the built-in completions complete on `C-z` this is the correct mapping:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <C-z> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() : (pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-z>")
```